Parsing command line args that can contain spaces
I am building a spring boot based command line utility written in java for teams in my organization. I will have to allow teams to pass arbitrary command line args that can contain spaces.
I tried looking up any third party libraries or libraries from Spring that can do this but I am not able to find any that can can parse args the way I want it.
java -jar client.jar --args='a=Car b=Truck c="Car faster than Truck" d="Car faster than all"'
In my command line utility I would like to get the args.
a=Car
b=Truck
c=Car faster than Truck
d=Car faster than all

I tried using regex to split by spaces and as you can tell it wouldnt work. I think splitting it based on spaces wouldnt work too.
What would be the efficient way to parse these args?

"as you can tell it wouldnt work" -- How would I tell that?

can the input be something like java -jar client.jar a=Car b=Truck "c=Car faster than Truck" "d=Car faster than all" - this would use the natural behavior of the (most) shell and would result in args[0]="a=Car", args[1]="b=Truck", args[2]="c=Car faster than Truck", args[3]="d=Car fasater than all"

Look into Spring Shell project

@user85421 The spring boot command line project wouldnt work this way because I think it requires the name of the parameter to get its value.

When talking about command line you need to take into account the quoting and escaping rules of the shell you are using in your OS. Are you using Windows cmd, powershell, bash, zsh or something else? They may understand quotes, doubles quotes and spaces differently.

@aled I am using bash.

Now I don't know anything about Spring-Boot but I'm going to take a chance here that the command line is similar to pretty much anything else. The overall goal here is to split the command-line string based on a whitespace but, not within double quote marks. You can do this with regex using a Positive Lookahead expression and the String#split() method. Below is a simple example (be sure to read the comments in code):
/* Splits the supplied command-line string based on one (or more) 
   whitespace(s) but, not those that are contained within double 
   quote marks. This utilizes a Positive Lookahead regular expression
   for the String#split() method. If you want an explanation of 
   the regex used below, then copy/Paste: 
            \s{1,}(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)
   into the Regular Expression bar in https://regex101.com/      */
String argsString = "'a=Car b=Truck c=\"Car faster than Truck\"  d=\"Car faster than all\"'";
    
String regex = "\\s{1,}(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)";
    
/* Not exactly sure if the single quotes at the beginnind and end 
   of of the overall command-line is actually delivered, so the `if` 
   block below removes them. If they are not part of the overall 
   command-line string then you can just delete this `if` block. */
if (argsString.startsWith("'") && argsString.endsWith("'")) {
    argsString = argsString.substring(1, argsString.length() - 1);
}
    
// Create an array of the provided command-line arguments:
String[] args = argsString.split(regex, -1);
    
/* If you want, remove the double-quote marks from tag values 
   within command-line elements:        */
for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    /* Done this way in case there are nested double-quote marks
       (for whatever reason) within the command line Tag Values.
       nested double-quote marks are NOT parsed out: */
    String[] tmp = args[i].split("=");
    if (tmp[1].startsWith("\"") && tmp[1].endsWith("\"")) {
        args[i] = tmp[0] + "=" + tmp[1].substring(1, tmp[1].length() - 1);
    }
}
    
// Display the command-line elements within the console window:
for (String str : args) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
    
System.out.println();
    
/* Further parsing would be to split each arg element 
   based on the "=" character:         */
System.out.println("Tag/Value Delimiter:   =");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
for (String arg : args) {
    String[] elements = arg.split("=");
    sb.append(String.format(
              "Argument Tag: -> %-5s Argument Value: -> %-25s%n", 
              elements[0], elements[1]
            ));
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());

If this code is tasked then you should see something like what is displayed below within the console window:
a=Car
b=Truck
c=Car faster than Truck
d=Car faster than all

Tag/Value Delimiter:   =
Argument Tag: -> a     Argument Value: -> Car                      
Argument Tag: -> b     Argument Value: -> Truck                    
Argument Tag: -> c     Argument Value: -> Car faster than Truck    
Argument Tag: -> d     Argument Value: -> Car faster than all      


This worked for me.
